# C# SQL Server stored procedure parameter return list

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, dapper

I'm attempting to execute a SQL Server stored procedure that takes two parameters and returns a list of results. The application is returning the results however I'm unsure how to assign the values to the list in the model. The ORM being utilized is Dapper. Here's my code

```
string startTime = "2018-04-17 00:00:00.000";
string endTime = "2018-04-17 23:59:59.997";
string db = "database";

List<ShelfInventoryModel> output = new List<ShelfInventoryModel>();

using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(SqlConnection.CnnString(db)))
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    var p = new DynamicParameters();
    p.Add("@StartDate", startTime);
    p.Add("@EndDate", endTime);

    output = connection.Query<ShelfInventoryModel>("dbo.spGetInventory_Liquor", p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();

    Console.WriteLine(output);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

This is the model class

```
public class ShelfInventoryModel
{
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
}
```

I understand that the results need to be filled into potentially a data adapter. However the system gives me an error when I attempt to fill the output to the data adapter

The purpose to return the results to the console. However, at this time the console is only showing:

> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ProcedureTest.ShelfInventoryModel]

Comment: What list "in the model"? Also, you don't need to assign `output` a new `List` if you're going to replace it with whatever `Query<...>(...).ToList()` returns.

Comment: The query returns the quantity and item name. Is the list not necessary in this scenario? While stepping through the application its returning an array of objects. I'd like to assign the objects to the list. Possibly using a foreach statement

Comment: At the end of the code you've shown, `output` should contain a list of `ShelfInventoryModel` objects. Can't see anything wrong with that code. So I'm really not sure *what you're trying to ask here*.

Comment: At the end of your code, `output` should contain a list of  `ShelfInventoryModel` objects, one for each row returned by the stored procedure, with the value from columns `Quantity` and `ItemName` put into those objects. (No need for a data adapter.)  So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: The purpose to return the results to the console. However, at this time the console is only returning System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ProcedureTest.ShelfInventoryModel]

Comment: That last comment is *critical* and should have been part of your question. It would have been better to [edit] your question with that information than put it in comments - I have done that for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Console.WriteLine(output);` will simply display the result of ToString on the parameter, which for this type reverts to the default implementation, which just shows the name of the type of the `output` object. You need to iterate through the items in the list using `foreach`:

```
foreach (var item in output)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Which would cause you to get a row of lines just giving the type of that object. So either you can write an implementation of ToString for your object, or simply display the bits you want to see...

```
foreach (var item in output)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.ItemName} {item.Quantity}");
}
```

Comment: This was my generally understanding as well. However, when I step through the statement the result being returned to the console is ProcedureTest.ShelfInventoryModel

Comment: Answer edited to explain why that's another instance of the same thing happening and how to overcome it.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much! Here's what I did in order to resolve my issue foreach(ShelfInventoryModel item in output)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{item.Quantity} {item.ItemName}");
                    
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
string startTime = "2018-04-17 00:00:00.000";
string endTime = "2018-04-17 23:59:59.997";
string db = "database";

List<ShelfInventoryModel> output = new List<ShelfInventoryModel>();

using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(SqlConnection.CnnString(db)))
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    var p = new DynamicParameters();
    p.Add("@StartDate", startTime);
    p.Add("@EndDate", endTime);

    output = connection.Query<ShelfInventoryModel>("dbo.spGetInventory_Liquor", p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();

    foreach (ShelfInventoryModel item in output)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Quantity.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(item.ItemName);
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working code in order for the application to return a list of results to the console

```
foreach(ShelfInventoryModel item in output)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{item.Quantity} {item.ItemName}");

            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```